# Installing a specific version of elastic search on dockers

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I want to install ES(6.1.1) on my docker container but refrencing a lot of material i only see i was by default able to download the latest version 6.2.4 which i don't want because i have certain packages in my code which doesn't work well with the latest version.

Download ES link
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-6-1-1

Docker file snippet

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https curl
RUN echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic.list
RUN  apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

As you can see here it's written 6.x  even if i change it to(ES VERSION 6.1.1) by copying the download link i get some buid error 404.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 5):

OK, this works for me from a base image of Ubuntu. You need to add the GPG key for the elastic repo to then install from it. Once that's done, you can specify a version in your final `apt-get` as I've done.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https curl wget
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install elasticsearch=6.1.1
```

Comment: i haven't changed the last two lines because i don't know what exactly i need to add . Though i'm able to get the correct version now but still getting some signature errors while building.

Comment: Reading package lists...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: What image are you building from? I'll try and reproduce your build. In the meantime, try `sudo apt-get install elasticsearch=6.1.1` as your last command if you haven't already...

Comment: i already have installed elasticsearch=6.1.1 with the above commands mentioned by you and only left with the error mentioned in the comment. It will be helpful if we you give me the build you are working on

Comment: I get A GPG signing error too if I comment out the second line `RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -`. When the line is there though, the build completes OK. Frustrating!

Comment: Yes it's frustrating.So what is the fix??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169693/discussion-between-brabster-and-codaholic).